# Jquery self-call function loop

Tags: jquery, function, loops, function-call

I'm trying to check whether my self-calling jquery function did the job done but what happened is that the result keep multiplying on each self calling.

HTML

```
<span id="checkit"></span>
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
    callme();
});

function callme(){
    $('#checkit').append("callme loaded<br />");
    setInterval("callme()", 5000);
}
```

Normally, here's my result for the codes.

onLoad.

```
callme loaded
```

5 seconds later

```
callme loaded <from previous
callme loaded
```

another 5 seconds later

```
callme loaded <from previous
callme loaded <from previous
callme loaded
callme loaded
callme loaded
callme loaded
```

Sorry for the crappy explanation. I've been thinking really hard why this stuffs happened. If anyone could explain what I did wrong, or the solution for this. Please help - This problem kept bugging me for days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you call `callme`, you are creating a new interval that will call `callme` again. You can clear the previous interval using `clearInterval` or use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

```
function callme(){
    $('#checkit').append("callme loaded<br />");
    setTimeout(callme, 5000);
}
```

Comment: thanks William, I'll be sure to remember the differences between setTimeout and setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the #checkit element has been created.  And, you need to use a timeout (which only calls once) instead of an interval (which goes on and on):

```
function callme(){
   $('#checkit').append("callme loaded<br />");
   if (!document.getElementById('checkit'))
      setTimeout(callme, 5000);
}
```

Reference for learning: [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout)

Comment: Is there a good reason to pass `"callme()"` instead of `callme`?

Comment: Stupid copy/paste mistake; fixed ;)

Comment: Yeah, I later noticed the OP had it in there.

Answer (score 0):

setInterval is not setTimeout. You are not clearing the interval, so they are compounding.